# 'X makes the device operate' or 'X makes the device operates'

Tags: complements, causative-make

If I use the word "make" before a verb, shall I add "s" to the verb coming after it?

> The mechanism *makes* the device **operates** and **retries**.

Or

> The mechanism *makes* the device **operate** and **retry**.

Comment: Your second example is correct. "Operate and retry" is a coordination of two subordinate infinitival (i.e. non-finite) clauses as complement of "makes". Such clauses are headed by a plain form verb, here, "operate" and "retry", not a tensed form like "operates" and "retries". Semantically, "the device" is subject of the subordinate clauses, but syntactically it is object of "makes", and hence is called a 'raised object'.

Comment: Does the *mechanism* retry, or does the mechanism make the *device* retry?

Answer (score 1):

After the '*[causative verb](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-causative-verb-1689833)*' **make** we use the **base form of the verb** *(as it is listed in a dictionary)*:

- Please, don't make me **do** it again. *("**do**" is the base form)*
- He will never make that car **turn** 360°. *("**turn**" is the base form)*

Your second option is correct:

> The mechanism makes the device operate and retry.

Answer (score 0):

> [1] *The mechanism makes the device operate and retry*.
>
> [2] * *The mechanism makes the device operates and retries*.

The simple answer to your question is no; you should not add an "s" to the verbs following "makes" because they are not 3rd person tensed forms, but plain forms. [2] is thus ungrammatical.

"Operate and retry" is a coordination of two subordinate infinitival (i.e. non-finite) clauses functioning as complements of "makes".

Non-finite clauses such as infinitivals require a plain form verb, in this case "operate" and "retry", not a tensed form like "operates" and "retries".

Semantically, "the device" is subject of the subordinate clauses, but syntactically it is object of "makes" in the main clause, and hence is called a 'raised object'.

Answer (score -1):

Some verbs, such as *make, let, see* and *hear*, may be followed by an infinitive without the infinitive marker *to*. Others, such as *help, dare,* and *need* may include the *to* in some contexts but are often found without.

> His mother made him go to school.
>
> He dared her to jump off the high diving board. **BUT** How dare you do that?

Your sentence is a classic example:

> The mechanism makes the device operate and retry.

The words *operate* and *retry* are infinitives without the *to*.